# How to use fluid particles to drive smoke simulation

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

The fluid simulation creates a particle system in the particle tab.
The smoke simulation can use particle systems to create smoke.

I cant seem to get the fluid simulation to drive my smoke simulation.

In rough terms i am having a non inflow single geo of water launched at a collision object and exploding. its got a detailed look and uses several effectors and force fields. i then want this to look like its make out of smoke.

**I have tried**

**1.** duplication the baked fluid sim domain. deleting the fluidsim (the particle sims still exist in the particles tab) then adding a fluid inflow and selecting the remaining particle system

-this produces nothing (the particle tab shows that there are however many particles at current frame but i cant get it to display them in the viewport)

**2.** baking out the fluid as a mesh then saving it as a alembic, reimporting it as a mesh sequence, then adding a particle system to its volume

-this works, but looks bad at the particles are random and cause little dots of smoke to randomly appear and there is no inherited movement from the fluid system, sadly this is the closest ive gotten.

**3.** Using guides. this does not appear to work in v3.5 but i got it working in v3.3. it is very slow and i cant not get it to match the look at all of the fluid system. this might be because the inflow cant be matched up maybe because the water is a geo of water that is launched and strikes a collision and goes all over. The only tutorial on this i have seen using a matching constant inflow for both water and smoke.

If anyone can give me any insight into this i would be most appreciative as searching for information on this has been rather hard.

Tanks for reading

-Borb